# Azure Service Fabric - SecurityAccessPolicy to access certificate for a specific service

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've a SF application with following structure.

```
Application1
 - ServiceA -> Deployed to NodeType1
 - ServiceB -> Deployed to NodeType2
 - ServiceC -> Deployed to NodeType2
 - ServiceD -> Deployed to NodeType2
```

**ServiceA** is a front-end service listening on TCP port and has some specific security requirements. Hence it is deployed on **NodeType1**.

**Service B,C & D** are back-end service, and deployed to **NodeType2**.

**ServiceA** requires NetworkServiceAccount to have access to a certificate which is installed only in **NodeType1**. And because this is not an endpoint certificate, I'm trying to define a SecurityAccessPolicy for this certificate resource. Initially I tried defining the following in AppManifest.xml.

```
<Principals>
  <Users>
    <User Name="SfServiceUser" AccountType="NetworkService" />
  </Users>
</Principals>
<Policies>
  <SecurityAccessPolicies>
    <SecurityAccessPolicy ResourceRef="TLS Certificate" PrincipalRef="SfServiceUser" ResourceType="Certificate" />
  </SecurityAccessPolicies>
</Policies>
<Certificates>
  <SecretsCertificate X509FindValue="[TlsCertificateThumbprint]" Name="TLS Certificate" />
</Certificates>
```

While registering ApplicationType, it failed with "Service Fabric Error: Failed to ACL folders or certificates required by application. Error:FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND". This was because "TLS Certificate" is installed only in NodeType1, but SF was looking for this certificate in NodeType2 as well.

As a workaround, I tried defining SecurityAccessPolicy in ServiceManifestImport section of AppManifest.xml, as below.

```
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="ProtocolGateway.Host.Fabric.FrontEndPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <Policies>
      <RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="SetupAdminUser" EntryPointType="Setup" />
      <RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="SfServiceUser" />
      <SecurityAccessPolicy ResourceRef="TLS Certificate" PrincipalRef="SfServiceUser" ResourceType="Certificate" />
    </Policies>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
```

But this failed with error too - "The ResouceRef 'TLS Certificate' in SecurityAccessPolicy is invalid. There is no matching Resource in the corresponding ServiceManifest."

Though SecurityAccessPolicy inside ServiceManifestImport section accepts ResourceType as Certificate, ServiceManifest doesn't support defining Certificate as a Resource. Only EndPoint is supported.

While I could define ServiceA in one ApplicationType and other services in a different ApplicationType, I don't intend to do that, as these are related services and I want to use SF versioning to manage upgrade and rollback.

Please suggest me alternate for handling this requirement.